# Subquery returned more than 1 value when there is no Subquery

Tags: .net, dapper

Dapper throws `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'` when there is no Subquery. Innerexception is also null.

My query is `SELECT * FROM dbo.someTable` and I use Dappers `Query<T>` method.

Does it look familiar to anyone ?

UPDATE:
I get same error when i run query at MSSQL Server Management Studio. It's odd. I'll keep updating.

UPDATE 2:
Sorry for trouble. It was a nicely concealed view.

Comment: Is `dbo.someTable` table or view?

Comment: It just noticed it was a view -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought it was a bug of Dapper but then I realized my query target was a view. If i did this mistake someone else can too. Leaving it here.